# Extremum of function of several variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maximal-and-prime-ideals

can anyone please suggest to me some good references for the topic of extremum of the function of several variables (I need a book which deals with more than two variables). Thank you very much.

Comment: Calculus (2nd, 3rd or 4th edition) - Rogawski

Comment: Thanks for the reference information.